# Sub queries in case statement

Tags: sql, subquery, case

I am trying put a case statement, this case statement is based on condition from 2 different sub queries. My problem is, I am not able get it work.

This SQL sub queries is giving a count which I am using in case statement.

Error I am getting is:

> Incorrrect syntax near x and y.

(which are my subqueries)

```
Select 'Days=' as Days,
case
when x.yest >=0 then '1 Day'
when y.DayBefore <=3 then '1 Day'
else '2 Day'
end as Days
from
(
Select count(*) as yest 
from
[Main], [DailyStatus]
where Approved_Date is null
Submitted_Date = cast(LAST_WEEKDAY_DATE as date) x,

(
Select count(*) as DayBefore
 from [Main], [DailyStatus]
where Approved_Date is null
and Submitted_Date = dateadd(dd, -1, cast(LAST_WEEKDAY_DATE as date))
)y
```

Below are my tables:

**Main**
Approved_Date
Submitted_Date

**DailyStatus**
Last_Weekday_date

I highly appreciate any help on this.
Thanks, Shikha

Comment: One thing is that you are missing the keyword `AND` in your WHERE Clause in the first subquery... as well as a rouge comma in the same area

Comment: and before x a closing parenthesis is missing (the one before that closes the cast).

Comment: Sort your brackets out: `x,` looks like it should have a ) bracket before it

Answer (score 1):

Indent your sql properly and it will make these things easier to spot

```
Select 
  'Days=' as Days,
  case
    when x.yest >=0 then '1 Day'
    when y.DayBefore <=3 then '1 Day'
    else '2 Day'
  end as Days
from
(
  Select 
    count(*) as yest 
  from
    [Main]
    CROSS JOIN
    [DailyStatus]
  where 
    Approved_Date is nulL AND 
    Submitted_Date = cast(LAST_WEEKDAY_DATE as date) 
) x
CROSS JOIN
(
  Select 
    count(*) as DayBefore
  from 
    [Main]
    CROSS JOIN 
    [DailyStatus]
  where 
    Approved_Date is null and 
    Submitted_Date = dateadd(dd, -1, cast(LAST_WEEKDAY_DATE as date))
)y
```

Also, doing your joins like that (`from table1, table2`) fell out of favour about 20 years ago. Please use modern join syntax

Comment: Bird- I indented the code but when I post it, it got un indented itself. Thanks a ton for Cross Join tip.

Comment: Cross join isn't often used, but your query didn't seem to have any related data entities so it's the correct option for the context

Answer (score 0):

Syntax errors edited, as well as some formatting to make it a bit easier to read. PS - not a fan of your implicit joins here. You should be explicit by using `<join type> JOIN .... ON...`

```
SELECT
      'Days=' AS [Days]
    , CASE
         WHEN [x].[yest] >= 0 THEN '1 Day'
         WHEN [y].[DayBefore] <= 3 THEN '1 Day'
      ELSE '2 Day'
      END AS     [Days]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
             COUNT(*) AS [yest]
        FROM
            [Main]
          , [DailyStatus]
        WHERE  [Approved_Date] IS NULL
             AND [Submitted_Date] = CAST([LAST_WEEKDAY_DATE] AS DATE)
    ) AS [x]
   ,
    (
        SELECT
             COUNT(*) AS [DayBefore]
        FROM
            [Main]
          , [DailyStatus]
        WHERE  [Approved_Date] IS NULL
             AND [Submitted_Date] = DATEADD([dd], -1, CAST([LAST_WEEKDAY_DATE] AS DATE))
    ) AS [y]
```